# Increase extent of vector layer with OGR or GDAL?

Tags: python, geospatial, gdal, ogr, extent

When using the OGR library or GDAL library with Python script, is it possible to increase the extent of a vector layer without actually adding new data points?  In my specific case, I would like to increase the extent of vector layers associated with gpx files so that when I convert them to rasters they all have the same pixel matrix.

EDIT:  An attempt of mine to use `gdal.Rasterize` does not produce a "tiff" file, nor does it cause an error to be reported:

```
import os
import gdal
import ogr    
import math

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\pipi\Documents\Rogaine\Tarlo\gpx')  #folder containing gpx files
vector_fn = '6_hour_Autumngaine_w_Tom_Elle.gpx'  #filename of input gpxfile
pixel_size = 20 #units are in m if gpx file is left in wgs84
raster_fn = '0011a.tif'  # Filename of the raster Tiff that will be created

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('GPX')
source_ds = driver.Open(vector_fn, 0)
source_layer = source_ds.GetLayer('track_points')  #returns the 'track points' layer of the data source
SR = source_layer.GetSpatialRef().ExportToWkt()

#_______USING VALUES FROM THE FILE___________
x_min1, x_max1, y_min1, y_max1 = source_layer.GetExtent()

pixel_sizey = pixel_size/(111.2*math.pow(10,3))  #determines an approximate x and y size because of geographic coordinates.
pixel_sizex = pixel_size/(math.cos(((y_max1 + y_min1)/2)*(math.pi/180))*111.2*math.pow(10,3))
print (pixel_sizey, pixel_sizex)
x_res = int((x_max1 - x_min1) / pixel_sizex)
y_res = int((y_max1 - y_min1) / pixel_sizey)
print (x_res, y_res)

layer_list = ['track_points']

gdal.Rasterize(raster_fn, vector_fn, format='GTiff', outputBounds=[x_min1, y_min1, x_max1, y_max1], outputSRS=SR, xRes=x_res, yRes=y_res, burnValues=[1], layers=layer_list)

target_ds = None
vector_fn = None
source_layer = None
source_ds = None
```

Comment: Are you using `gdal.Rasterize()`?

Comment: No, I am using `gdal.RasterizeLayer()`.

Comment: I would appreciate help, or, a copy of python code that works using gdal.Rasterize() even if it is for another purpose.  My efforts to use gdal.Rasterize() do not result in no tiff being produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `options=gdal.RasterizeOptions(format='GTiff', outputBounds=[x_min1, y_min1, x_max1, y_max1], outputSRS=SR, xRes=x_res, yRes=y_res, burnValues=[1], layers=layer_list)` instead of passing the individual `kwargs` directly. Otherwise, they will be ignored, and the command won't do what you intend. See [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210729085314/https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#RasterizeOptions) and [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220328010331/https://gdal.org/python/) for details and links to the source code (often useful given the terse documentation).

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a method to change the extent of the vector layer.  However, I was able to write a python Function that uses gdal.RasterizeLayer() to produce a raster with an extent much larger than the original vector layer.  The code for this function is:

```
import os
import gdal
import ogr    

def RasterizeLarge(name, layer, extent, pixel_size):
    """Used to rasterize a layer where the raster extent is much larger than the layer extent
    Arguments:
    name       -- (string) filename without extension of raster to be produced
    layer      -- (vector layer object) vector layer containing the data to be rasterized (tested with point data)
    extent     -- (list: x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max) extent of raster to be produced
    pixel_size -- (list: x_pixel_size, y_pixel_size) 1 or 2 pixel different pixel sizes may be sent
    """

    if isinstance(pixel_size, (list, tuple)):
        x_pixel_size = pixel_size[0]
        y_pixel_size = pixel_size[1]

    else:
        x_pixel_size = y_pixel_size = pixel_size

    x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = extent    
    # determines the x and y resolution of the file (lg = large)
    x_res_lg = int((x_max - x_min) / x_pixel_size)+2
    y_res_lg = int((y_max - y_min) / y_pixel_size)+2

    if x_res_lg > 1 and y_res_lg > 1:
        pass
    else:
        print ('Your pixel size is larger than the extent in one dimension or more')
        return

    x_min_sm, x_max_sm, y_min_sm, y_max_sm = layer.GetExtent()

    if x_min_sm > x_min and x_max_sm < x_max and y_min_sm > y_min and y_max_sm < y_max:
        pass
    else:
        print ('The extent of the layer is in one or more parts outside of the extent provided')
        return

    nx = int((x_min_sm - x_min)/x_pixel_size) #(number of pixels between main raster origin and minor raster)
    ny = int((y_max - y_max_sm)/y_pixel_size)

    x_res_sm = int((x_max_sm - x_min_sm) / x_pixel_size)+2
    y_res_sm = int((y_max_sm - y_min_sm) / y_pixel_size)+2

    #determines upper left corner of small layer raster
    x_min_sm = x_min + nx * x_pixel_size
    y_max_sm = y_max - ny * y_pixel_size

    #______Creates a temporary raster file for the small raster__________
    try:
        # create the target raster file with 1 band
        sm_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create('tempsmall.tif', x_res_sm, y_res_sm, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
        sm_ds.SetGeoTransform((x_min_sm, x_pixel_size, 0, y_max_sm, 0, -y_pixel_size))
        sm_ds.SetProjection(layer.GetSpatialRef().ExportToWkt())
        gdal.RasterizeLayer(sm_ds, [1], layer, burn_values=[1])

        sm_ds.FlushCache()
        #______Gets data from the new raster in the form of an array________
        in_band = sm_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
        in_band.SetNoDataValue(0)
        sm_data = in_band.ReadAsArray()
    finally:
        sm_ds = None  #flushes data from memory.  Without this you often get an empty raster.

    #_____Creates an output file with the provided name and extent that contains the small raster.
    name = name + '.tif'

    try:
        lg_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(name, x_res_lg, y_res_lg, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)

        if lg_ds is None:
            print 'Could not create tif'
            return
        else:
        pass

        lg_ds.SetProjection(layer.GetSpatialRef().ExportToWkt())
        lg_ds.SetGeoTransform((x_min, x_pixel_size, 0.0, y_max, 0.0, -y_pixel_size))
        lg_band = lg_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
        lg_data = in_band.ReadAsArray()

        lg_band.WriteArray(sm_data, xoff = nx, yoff = ny)
        lg_band.SetNoDataValue(0)
        lg_band.FlushCache()
        lg_band.ComputeStatistics(False)
        lg_band = None

    finally:
        del lg_ds, lg_band, in_band
        os.remove('tempsmall.tif')
    return
```